# jQuery, parse single xml list into multiple unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, list, parsing

Source XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<area>
    <ticket>
        <ticketnumber>001</ticketnumber>
        <location>Location</location>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <ticketnumber>001</ticketnumber>
        <location>Location</location>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <ticketnumber>001</ticketnumber>
        <location>Location</location>
    </ticket>...
</area>
```

I can parse this into an existing un-ordered list using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "feed.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('ticket').each(function(){
                    var varTicket = $(this).find('ticketnumber').text();
                    var varLocation = $(this).find('location').text();
                    var varTheHTML = '<li>'+varTicket+' '+varLocation+'</li>';
                    $(varTheHTML).appendTo("#ticket-test");
                });
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("The XML File could not be processed correctly.");
        }
    });

});
```

This provides me with a populated list as expected.

```
<ul id="ticket-test">
    <li>001 Location</li>
    <li>001 Location</li>
    <li>001 Location</li>...
</ul>
```

The problems begin to arise when I need to split this list into multiple lists, ideally nested in the master list.  The new structure would now be:

```
<ul id="ticket-test">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>001 Location</li>
            <li>001 Location</li>
            <li>001 Location</li>...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>001 Location</li>
            <li>001 Location</li>
            <li>001 Location</li>...
        </ul>
    </li>...
</ul>
```

The source XML is essentially a flat list, so I need to assign these list items into chunks of, say, 10 or so (used later with unslider).

I have tried running counters within the .each function and using a return false to jump back out again, but the code quickly becomes a spaghetti junction, I'm certain there is a more elegant way of achieving this.

I've also tried .split and for loops, but keep hitting a brick wall.

Comment: Is second nested `<ul>` duplicate of first nested `<ul>`?

Comment: Not a duplicate (sorry, it's not clear in the description), the first nested list is the first 10 items in the xml, the second list is the next 10 items in the list, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "feed.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        var html = '<li><ul>';
        var counter = 10;
        $(xml).find('ticket').each(function(i, v) {
          var varTicket = $(v).find('ticketnumber').text();
          var varLocation = $(v).find('location').text();
          if (i > 0 && i % counter == 0) {
            html += '</ul></li><li><ul>';
          }
          html += '<li>' + varTicket + ' ' + varLocation + '</li>';



        });
        $(html + '</ul></li>').appendTo("#ticket-test");
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("The XML File could not be processed correctly.");
      }
    });

  });
```

see demo:https://jsfiddle.net/y0d1or6h/

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)  The code appears to stall at:  

`if(i%10 == 0 ){ html+='<li><ul>'}`

Comment: what do you mean by stall at?

Comment: Sorry, will clarify.  If i run as-is noting will be appended to #ticket-test.  If i remove the following, the script will run:

`                        if(i%10 == 0 ) {
                            html+='<li><ul>';
                        }
                            html+= '<li>'+varTicket+' '+varLocation+'</li>';

                        if(i%10 == 0 ) {
                            html+='</ul></li>';
                        }`

Comment: Genius! Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks also for the other responses, I unfortunately did not have time to review, however I do hope they help others with the same problem in the future.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hi @madalinivascu I don't suppose you would know how to produce the same output when parsing a JSON feed instead of an XML feed?  The JSON feed would be:

Comment: @RealBob use the dot notation `varJSONFeed[0].Identifier.UniqueId`

Comment: here https://jsfiddle.net/dzw21hLm/2/ if you have any other problem post another question

Comment: Thanks @madalinivascu !  Here is what I ended up with, works great:

Answer (score 0):

Please check this approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var xmlString =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>' +
    '<area>' +
    '<ticket>' +
    '<ticketnumber>001</ticketnumber>' +
    '<location>Location</location>' +
    '</ticket>' +
    '<ticket>' +
    '<ticketnumber>002</ticketnumber>' +
    '<location>Location</location>' +
    '</ticket>' +
    '<ticket>' +
    '<ticketnumber>003</ticketnumber>' +
    '<location>Location</location>' +
    '</ticket>' +
    '<ticket>' +
    '<ticketnumber>004</ticketnumber>' +
    '<location>Location</location>' +
    '</ticket>' +
    '<ticket>' +
    '<ticketnumber>005</ticketnumber>' +
    '<location>Location</location>' +
    '</ticket>' +
    '<ticket>' +
    '<ticketnumber>006</ticketnumber>' +
    '<location>Location</location>' +
    '</ticket>' +
    '</area>';

  var xmlDoc = jQuery.parseXML(xmlString);
  var tempUL = $('<ul></ul>'); //creating a temp ul tag
  $(xmlDoc).find('ticket').each(function() {
    var varTicket = $(this).find('ticketnumber').text();
    var varLocation = $(this).find('location').text();
    var varTheHTML = '<li>' + varTicket + ' ' + varLocation + '</li>';
    tempUL.append(varTheHTML)

  });
  
  //change below number as per your requirement
  var numberOfLi = 3;
  
  while (1) {

    var liSet = tempUL.find("li:lt(" + numberOfLi + ")").detach(); //detaching the set of li to make new ul 
    var newUL = $("<ul></ul>").append(liSet);
    var topLI = $("<li></li>").append(newUL);
    topLI.appendTo("#ticket-test");

    if (tempUL.find("li").length == 0)
      break;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
my list
<ul id="ticket-test"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing pattern at Question, then utilize `.slice()`, `.wrapAll()`, `.parent()`, `.wrap()`, recursion. Create two variables defined as `0`, `10` respectively, increment variables by `10` within recursive call to function, if greatest variable is less than or equal to total `#ticket-test li`  `.length`

```js
var tickets = $("#ticket-test li");

function wrapListItems (el, num, i = 0, n = num) {
  if (n <= tickets.length) {
    el.slice(i, n).wrapAll("<ul>").parent().wrap("<li>");
    i += num;
    n += num;
    wrapListItems(el, num, i, n);
  } 
};

wrapListItems(tickets, 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul id="ticket-test">
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
  <li>001 Location</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 2;//change to whatever u need
var mainHtmlElement = $('#ticket-test');
var htmlElement;

$('xml').find('ticket').each(function(index){
  if(index % counter == 0) {
    htmlElement = $('<ul class="level_2"></ul>');
    var el_li = $('<li class="level_1"></li>');
    htmlElement.appendTo(el_li);
    el_li.appendTo(mainHtmlElement);
  }
  var varTicket = $(this).find('ticketnumber').text();
  var varLocation = $(this).find('location').text();
  htmlElement.append('<li class="level_2">'+varTicket+' '+varLocation+'</li>');
});
```